# taylor series involving Mobius function

Tags: power-series

is there a formulae for the function

$$ g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mu (n) x^{n} $$

i presume that i must use the Lambert series

$$ x= \sum_ {n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mu (n) x^{n}}{1-x^{n}} $$

Comment: What is the definition of $\mu$?

Comment: This might interest you: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126442/ordinary-generating-function-for-mobius

Comment: @FlybyNight apparently the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Dirichlet convolution:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \tag{1}$$
for every $s\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\text{Re}(s)>1$. It follows that:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{g(x)-1}{x}(-\log x)^{s-1}\,dx =\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\zeta(s)}\tag{2}$$
or, by setting $x=e^{-t}$,
$$ \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(g(e^{-t})-1\right)t^{s-1}\,dt = (\mathcal{M}\,f)(s)\tag{3} $$
with $f(x)=g(e^{-x})-1$ and $\mathcal{M}$ being the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform). By the inversion formula,
$$ g(e^{-x})-1 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{x^s \zeta(s)}\,ds\tag{4} $$
as soon as $c>1$.

Comment: What is $\mu(0) $ ? I think the OP meant $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) x^n$ (for $|x| < 1$)

Comment: @user1952009: I assumed $\mu(0)=1$ in the above lines, but if the series defining $g(x)$ starts at $n=1$ there is very little to fix.